# Replace string with common phrase after matching string in two different dataframes R

Tags: r, regex, match

trying to write a line of code that compares strings in one column of dataframe against a reference string and if it matches replace with a common word.  For example, search column A and look for matches in column B and replace the matching string with word 'name'

Thoughts?

Example:

```
v1 <- c("corey joe","joe", "emily", "joe")
v2 <- c("corey", "emily")
```

final output should be:

```
v1 = "name joe joe name joe"
```

I've used

```
ifelse(pmatch(v1, v2), 'name')
NA NA name NA
```

with partial success, but it doesn't change corey to name because google is also in that character string.  It also converts joe to NA and I need to keep it joe

Any help would be greatly appreciated - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You may use stringr's **str_replace**:

```
library(stringr)

value <- str_replace(v1,"corey|emily","name")

> str_replace(v1,"corey|emily","name")
[1] "name joe" "joe"      "name"     "joe"
```

In case you want everything into one string,you can use `collapse` option in `paste` as below:

```
> paste(value,collapse=" ")
[1] "name joe joe name joe"
```

In case you want to use **gsub** from BASE R

```
  value <- gsub("corey|emily","name",v1)

> gsub("corey|emily","name",v1)
[1] "name joe" "joe"      "name"     "joe"     
>
 > paste(value,collapse=" ")
[1] "name joe joe name joe"
```

In case you want to use variable then you can use **paste0**:

```
str_replace(v1,paste0(v2[1],"|",v2[2]),"name")
```

More precisely :

```
str_replace(v1,paste0(v2[1:length(v2)],collapse="|"),"name")
```

**EDIT After the comment:**
And I admit, SO is a great place, As suggested by **@Scarabee**, added very simpler solution which is `str_replace(v1,v2,"name")`

```
> value <- str_replace(v1,paste0(v2,collapse="|"),"name")
> final <- paste(value,collapse=" ")
> final
[1] "name joe joe name joe"
```

Results would be same.